# CollectionView estimated size sets all cells at same size

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to implement estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height / 6) in my collectionview to resize the cells vertically to fit the content within them. This line resizes all cells in the collection to the same height and cuts off the content in some cells.

Whats best way to achieve cell resizing vertically to fit content?  Im not sure about using autoLayout as i get lots of console warnings about constraints when i have used it before with collection view cells which then have size set in code.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing width and height based off screen width/height by getting that info from UIDevice

Comment: Yeah I've done that in other cases. But the screen height isn't going to help me set the height based on the content of the cell

Comment: If the data is coming from internet, maybe store data for the height you want it and when your collection view is called, get the height data from internet to set height.